# Why JavaScript wont execute?

Tags: javascript, html, numbers

whats wrong please tell me

i am trying to make the number goes higher whenever i press enter key

```js
        function prep2() {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
               var number = parseInt(document.getElementById('num').value);
            document.getElementById("num").innerHTML=number + 1;
            }
        }
```

```css
body {
             font-family: Arial;
             font-size: 50px;
         }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        
<title>Game</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <input type="text" onkeypress="prep2()" id="num">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to set the innerHTML property on an input and instead, need to modify the value property.

Change this:

`document.getElementById("num").innerHTML=number + 1;`

To this:

`document.getElementById("num").value=number + 1;`

```js
function prep2() {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    var number = parseInt(document.getElementById('num').value);
    document.getElementById("num").value = number + 1;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title>Game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" onkeypress="prep2()" id="num">
</body>

</html>
```